# How to resolve error 'overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function'

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I know this 'If a virtual function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the exception-specification of the base class virtual function.'
But the problem is I am not writing the code, it is legacy on which I am working.

Everywhere it is explained that what it is but nowhere it is mentioned how to resolve the issue.

This is the virtual function in the base.h file:

```
virtual LONG A() throw()
    {
        return Model::Decrement(&m_nLockCnt);
    }
```

and I am getting an error in app.h file :

```
class CServerAppModule : public CAppModule
{
    LONG A()
        {
            LONG lR = CModule::A();
            if(lR == 0)
            {
                //
            }
            return lR;
        }
};
```

Comment: Did you try adding `throw()` to the overridden function or removing it from the base function? The problem here is that a caller of CAppModule::A() will assume the function does not throw, but CServerAppModule's implementation actually can throw.

Comment: If you're using C++17, you should switch away from using `throw()` and use `noexcept`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the base class the line `virtual LONG A() throw()` means that a function A is introduced that takes no parameters and returns `LONG`. The function is specified to not throw exceptions. In modern C++ you would replace `throw()` with `noexcept`.

In your derived class the function is overriden as `LONG A()`. This function also takes no parameters and also returns `LONG`. But this function is allowed to throw exceptions.

So there is a conflict. The base class says that `A` does not throw, but the derived class says that `A` can throw.

The solution: both `A`should agree on the same exception specification: either both use `throw()` (better: `noexcept`) or both don't use `throw()` or `noexcept`.